# Elements dissapear on addClass jQuery method

Tags: jquery, css

I have some elements with `position: fixed`. Once the remaining elements have been scrolled a sufficient amount I want to change the fixed elements to absolute so that they start moving as well.

The elements have baked into their CSS `position: fixed`. Once the page has scrolled a certain amount I use jQuery and `.addClass('absolute')` where this class has the rule `position: absolute !important`. (I was finding that for one element where the absolute was defined on an id selector that this would take precedent over the new class rule)

What then happens is that the elements to which I added the class then disappear. On scrolling back, I would remove the class and the elements would reappear. I don't know why.

All the code so far is at [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LfFBH)

Comment: The element hasn't disappeared; it's at the very top of the page, which has scrolled up out of view. What did you expect to happen? Especially since you haven't assigned any `left` or `top` values to the element.

Answer (score 0):

So I took a gander at the codepen and your element is still there, its just at the top. Since your actual parent container isn't moving nor is it postion relative the sidebar will be position in relation to the page.

You can see this when you inspect it and scroll down, as soon as it 'disappears' its actually at the top of the page, you cannot see it because you are too far down.

What do you need it to do though? Hope this helps! :)

Comment: With everything fixed, depending on the height of the sidebar the footer may or may not be in view. So once the main contenthas been scrolled up so that the bottom of #scroll is level with the bottom of the footer, I then want the whole page to scroll upwards. The inspiration for the designer was [Jukebot](http://www.gonzalves.fr/jukebot/).

Comment: it seems what you have with position fixed is accomplish the jukebot effect. Rather than trying to make the sidebar know where it is I would maybe just set some padding under the content container so it wouldn't overlap the footer. If you wanted to really do it that way you may have to compare the .top() of the footer with the bottom most part of the sidebar and from there decide if you need start scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need to set a `top` value for an absolutely positioned element - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ubjvD

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to do the reverse (start with `position: absolute` and use `position: fixed`) or just use `position: fixed` the whole time.  When you switch to `absolute`, the element will will be positioned at where it would start in the DOM.  It is merely being scrolled off screen.